# Turning a Product of Events into a Product of Conditional Probabilities

Tags: probability, terminology

Is there a name for the following identity?
$$
\begin{align*}
& \Pr\left(\bigwedge_{i=1}^n A_i \mid B \right)\\
&= \Pr\left(A_1 \mid B \right) \cdot \Pr(A_2 \mid A_1 \wedge B) \cdot \Pr(A_3 \mid A_1 \wedge A_2 \wedge B) \cdots \Pr\left(A_n \mid \bigwedge_{i = 1}^{n-1} A_i \wedge B \right)
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like the *product rule* or *chain rule* or *multiplication rule*
 for the probability of the intersection of $n$  events:
$$P(A_1A_2\cdots A_n) = P(A_1)P(A_2|A_1)P(A_3|A_1A_2)\cdots P(A_n|A_1A_2\cdots A_{n-1})$$
except that everything is conditioned on the event $B$.  See, for example, S. Ross
*A First Course in Probability,*  Eighth edition, page 63.